# How to set HOSTNAME in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

In Bash, which sets `$HOSTNAME` for you, I was able to calculate the total length of prompt line simply by using something like:
`PS1_length=$((${#USER}+${#HOSTNAME}+${#PWDNAME}+12+${#PS1_GIT}))`

It was useful e.g. when creating the fill-line like this: [image]

However `zsh` fails to set `$HOSTNAME` correctly and I can't think of a way to emulate the similar behavior in it — any thoughts?

Comment: @Janis I have zsh 5.0.2 and HOSTNAME is not set, I had to do that myself. Did you start zsh from another shell that exported that variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just set

```
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
```

in your `~/.zshrc`

Or as Caleb pointed out there is a variable HOST set, so to keep your prompt portable you could also do:

```
HOSTNAME=$HOST
```

Comment: If you want HOSTNAME to be set you should get your system to do it properly. The shell's rc file is not the best place for that and if you don't want to depend on the system the shell has a proper environment variable for you to use ready to go without this hack.

Comment: @Caleb - How is setting an environment variable in the shell's environment file with the output of the eponymous basic system utility supposed to be a hack exactly? You might argue that it should be set in `profile` - `zsh` doesn't honor that anyway, and the various flavors of `zsh`init vary widely even on the names of sourced files used during the process. One thing they all seem pretty much to agree on, however, is `.zshrc` *(in some form or another)*

Comment: @Anthon The features and syntax of the ZSH prompt are not particularly portable to other shells anyway. In this context why would you not just use the variable that ZSH expects and has setup for you? Why set another one at all? Incidentally using HOSTNAME in this context _does_ cause a portability problem if you try to pass your prompt off on somebody else. They would need to setup their profile to match your variable renaming rather than just being able to drop in usage of HOME.

Comment: @Caleb because then the OP would have prompt that would only work on zsh, and by the time he decides to move back or move onwards (for whatever reason) he has to adapt that again. I assume the OP is more concerned about being able to go back to `bash` than handing over things to someone else. At least I was when I tried `zsh`.

Comment: @Anthon Prompt escapes in bash and zsh are completely different, so there's no point in looking for compatibility there.

Comment: Quickly answer, bad answer. Not zsh guidelines

Comment: Tip: HOSTNAME=$(hostname -f) for full hostname!

Answer (score 11):

`zsh` prompt expansion lets you do that prompt without having to do any calculation:

```
PS1='%$COLUMNS>╡>%F{cyan}╔╡%F{red}[%n]%F{cyan}:%F{yellow}[%m]%F{cyan}➾%F{green}[%~]%F{default}$PS1_GIT%F{cyan}${(l:COLUMNS::═:):-}%<<
╚═╡%F{default}'
```

Explained:

- `%$COLUMNS>╡>`: right-truncate to `$COLUMNS` (a variable set dynamically by `zsh` to the width of the terminal) the part up to the next `%<<`.
- `%F{color}`: set the foreground colour
- `%n`, `%m`, `%~`: user name, machine name (hostname up to the first dot), current directory with `~`-named-dirs.
- `${(l:COLUMNS::═:):-}`: left-pad the empty string (`${:-}`) to `$COLUMNS` length with `═` characters.

`%m` is like `${HOST%%.*}`. If you want the full host name (`$HOST`), use `%M` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to get my Chinese computer name/machine name to display in zsh themes i.e. 外星. `PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%m%`. The normal Mac Sharing prefs displays the computer name in Chinese, but shell ends up changing it to the roman characters that represent that Chinese i.e. weixing. Is there any way to get machine names in other languages to display in a shell or will it always default to English since the local host name is always forced to English as well?

Comment: @tymac, `zsh` wouldn't be doing that translation AFAIK. Possibly your terminal emulator or the `gethostname()`/`uname()` API does. Testing here with GNU terminal, those characters (even though they are double-width) don't seem to be causing a problem when used in the current working directory at least (`%~` above).

Comment: @tymac, what's the output of `uname -n | od -tx1 -tc`? You might want to ask a separate question BTW, as it has little to do with this one.

Comment: Here you go :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351097/how-to-get-chinese-machine-name-to-display-in-shell

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong variable name. The `$HOSTNAME` environment variable is often set by the host system's init routines, but not always. In the context of a ZSH profile you should use the environment variable `$HOST` which is explicitly set by the shell. From `man zshall`:

> PARAMETERS SET BY THE SHELL
>       […]
>       HOST   The current hostname.

Note in that list that `$HOSTNAME` is not something that ZSH attempts to set, it is only set or not on the whim of your system's init system.

Also note that `$HOST` is not something you should use in cross platform shell scripting if you are hoping for portability to other shells—in that case the `hostname` binary is likely your best bet—but in the context of a ZSH profile the shell's own variable is the most appropriate thing to use.

Comment: `uname -n` would be a better bet.