# Display Chinese machine name in shell prompt

Tags: osx, zsh

I'm trying to get my Chinese computer name/machine name to display in a zsh prompt i.e. 飞碟. `PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%m%`. The normal Mac Sharing prefs displays the computer name in Chinese, but shell ends up changing it to the roman characters (pinyin) that represent that Chinese i.e. feidie. Is there any way to get machine names in other languages to display in a shell or will it always default to English since the local host name is always forced to English as well?

Here is the output of `uname -n | od -tx1 -tc`

> ```
> 0000000    66  65  69  64  69  65  2e  6c  6f  63  61  6c  0a            
>             f   e   i   d   i   e   .   l   o   c   a   l  \n
> ```

Comment: It looks like the hostname is `feidie`, but `飞碟` is the computer description (some text setting that is specific to macOS, so you'd need to find the right macOS API to query that string)

Comment: According to [How do I find my "computer description" in a Java application on Windows and/or Mac?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3934375), it looks like it's `scutil --get computerName`

Comment: Yes I've been to that page :) It's `scutil --get ComputerName`. It returns the Chinese properly. Which means that %m name is actually printing the localhost name (since the localhost name always defaults (is forced) to English). `scutil --get LocalHostName ` returns feidie. `scutil --get HostName` returns "not set".

Comment: yes `%m` is the host name (same as output of `uname -n`) like on any other Unix-likes. While the output of `scutil --get ComputerName` is something that is macOS specific. Some other OS or OS software (like samba or avahi) can give some form or another of textual description of the computer, that's not what `zsh` uses there either. It can only reasonably rely on the standard _host name_ which can be retrieved using a [standard API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html).

Comment: just add a `HOST_DESCRIPTION=$(scutil --get ComputerName)` in your `~/.zshrc` and use that `$HOST_DESCRIPTION` in your prompt. Or use `$(scutil --get ComputerName)` in the prompt though that would mean running that command at each prompt for something that hardly ever changes.

Comment: It works. See my question edit. Also please add your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Stéphane for the HOST_DESCRIPTION swizzle

```
# .zshrc
HOST_DESCRIPTION=$(scutil --get ComputerName)

# PROMPT
PROMPT='%F{yellow}${HOST_DESCRIPTION}%f'
```

[image]